# I can't open phpmyadmin after restarting my computer

Tags: phpmyadmin, localhost

I have installed xampp. Port 80 was already in use. So I used port 8079 for apache by making modification in httpd-conf and httpd-ssl.conf. I made a database in phpmyadmin. Everything was working fine. Later when I restarted my pc and tried to open phpmyadmin, I am getting a message

> Connection attempt to localhost was rejected

Please give me a solution to 
this problem. I have already tried uninstalling xampp and installing it back. It works fine untill I shut down my pc. On restarting, I get the same error again.